# Cannot write to Windows volume from Linux container using NLog

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nlog, docker-volume

I have an ASP.NET Core application running in a Linux container on a Windows host system. I'm trying to use NLog within the container to write logs back to the host system.

I dynamically set my NLog configuration in the Program startup, as opposed to using an `nlog.config` file:

```
var configuration = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

var file = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("file") 
{ 
    FileName = @"/logs/logfile-${shortdate}.log", 
    Layout="${message}" 
};

var console = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("console")
{
    Layout = "${message}"
};

configuration.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, file);
configuration.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, console);

NLog.LogManager.Configuration = configuration;
```

And I run my container from Windows with:

```
docker run --rm -v D:\logs:/logs imagename
```

My application runs successfully, the console logs appear as expected, and the `D:\logs` directory gets created. But I don't get the log file in the `D:\logs` directory on the host system.

Is there something missing in my NLog configuration or am I not correctly mounting the volume?

Comment: It is recommended to enable [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) when troubleshooting NLog (Can be redirected to console). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting